# Combining GridLayout and FillLayout without adding FormLayout?

Tags: java, layout, swt

Java SWT provides four standard layout classes: `FillLayout`, `RowLayout`, `GridLayout`, `FormLayout`.  I know how to use each of the layout classes, but struggle when combining layout classes.

For example, I have a screen in my application that uses a `GridLayout`.  I wish to add two vertical (i.e. `FillLayout`) layouts; One layout to the left of the `GridLayout` and the other layout to the right of the `GridLayout`.  Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to get my desired overall layout (i.e. see ascii art at the bottom).

There are sample answers given at the SO link below, but I want to avoid changing the code too much by adding a FormLayout.

[can I combine SWT GridLayout and FillLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846509/can-i-combine-swt-gridlayout-and-filllayout)

Is there sample code that will allow me to add two FillLayouts to a Grid Layout without using a FormLayout?  Should look like the below (ignore the badly pasted ascii in the right-most FillLayout).

```
+-------------+      +-------------------------------------------+          +--------------+
|             |      |                                           |      |                      |
|             |      |                                           |      |                  |
|             |      |                                           |      |                      |
|             |      |                                           |      |                      |
|  Fill Layout|      |     Grid Layout                           |      |      Fill Layout |
|             |      |                                           |      |                  |
|             |      |                                           |      |                  |
|             |      |                                           |      |                  |
|             |      |                                           |      |                  |
|             |      |                                           |      |                  |
|             |      |                                           |      |                  |
|             |      |                                           |      |                  |
|             |      |                                           |      |                  |
|             |      |                                           |      |                  |
|             |      |                                           |      |                  |
|             |      |                                           |      |                  |
|             |      |                                           |      |                  |
|             |      |                                           |      |                  |
+-------------+      +-------------------------------------------+          +--------------+
```

Comment: So you want to 2 fill layout and a Grid layout in a SWT application without adding Form Layout.  Is that correct?

Comment: @SubashJ Correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below code and let me know if you are looking similar to that.

I am using `Absolute Layout` for the shell and I have created 3 composites inside my application and applied `Fill Layout` for 2 composite and `Grid Layout` for 1 composite. Refer the code below

```
public class SampleWindow {

    protected Shell shell;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SampleWindow window = new SampleWindow();
            window.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Open the window.
     */
    public void open() {
        Display display = Display.getDefault();
        createContents();
        shell.open();
        shell.layout();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create contents of the window.
     */
    protected void createContents() {
        shell = new Shell();
        shell.setSize(531, 363);
        shell.setText("SWT Application");

        Composite composite = new Composite(shell, SWT.BORDER);
        composite.setBounds(10, 10, 131, 304);
        composite.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));

        Label lblNewLabel = new Label(composite, SWT.NONE);
        lblNewLabel.setText("Fill Layout");

        Composite composite_1 = new Composite(shell, SWT.BORDER);
        composite_1.setBounds(159, 10, 199, 304);
        composite_1.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, false));
        Label lblNewLabel_1 = new Label(composite_1, SWT.NONE);
        lblNewLabel_1.setText("Grid Layout");

        Composite composite_2 = new Composite(shell, SWT.BORDER);
        composite_2.setBounds(382, 10, 123, 304);
        composite_2.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));

        Label lblNewLabel_2 = new Label(composite_2, SWT.NONE);
        lblNewLabel_2.setText("Fill Layout");

    }
}
```

**Output will be similar like below:**

[image: Sample SWT application window]

Comment: Using `setBounds` on everything like that is generally not a good idea. You should let the layout handle the size for you.